# how to respond to user expanding a node?

Tags: fancytree, jbox

I guess the answer is `expand` - but the `expand`-event does not seem to fire.

But let me start at the beginning: I have a nice tree and I'd like to use [jBox](https://stephanwagner.me/jBox) to display information about certain nodes. I noticed that this worked only for nodes that were visible when the tree was created, but it did not work for nodes under collapsed nodes. So I thought I could use `expand`and assign an event-handler that would call `jBox`to create the tooltips. But it did not work. I added a `console.log` to the `expand-handler and noticed that it never logged.
Am I specifying it incorrectly?

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/pgh52m4w/1/). The "SD"-Node has some items in it which should have a tooltip attached to the (i)-icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't fire because you are passing in a string:

`"expand": "function(event, data) {...}"`

You need to remove the double quotes, so that it is a function:

`"expand": function(event, data) {...}`

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgh52m4w/3/

The same counts for the event "dblclick". Remove the double quotes there too.

Also, it is encouraged to use the `.attach()` method when attaching jBox. The attach method will check if this jBox was already attached to the element and only attaches it if it wasn't.

See the updated fiddle. I created a variable for the tooltip and reattach it in the expand event:

```
$(function() {
  var treei = $("#tree").fancytree({
    expand: function () {
      myTooltip && myTooltip.attach(); // Reattaching Tooltip
    }
    // ...
  });
  var myTooltip = new jBox("Tooltip", { // get tooltips showing
    attach: '[data-jbox-content]',
    getTitle: "data-jbox-title",
    getContent: "data-jbox-content"
  });
});
```

Comment: <blush> Don't know what to say but "THANKS!" :-) That attach-bit is useful, thanks - now I see the purpose of that option...